# Bootstrap table keys up , down function in multiple tables

Tags: jquery

I have multiple tables. For example maybe I will select first table for change rows with keys then second table and then maybe I will select first table. This code work well for keys but effects all tables. I tried make it with hover its not work as I want. Thanks

```
     var testid = null; 
     $(document).ready(function(e) { 
     $("#example tr").click(function() { 
     $(this).addClass('selected').siblings().removeClass('selected');


     testid = $("tr.selected td").attr("value");
     $.ajax({
    url: '../aksesuar/testkod.php',  
    type: 'POST',   
    data: { 'kateqoriya': testid } , 
    success: function(data){
        $('#testaksesuar').html(data);   
           $('#aksesuar').attr('value', testid);       
    }
    });
    });
    $("#example td").click(function() { 
    $("#example tr.selected").removeClass("selected"); 
    $(this).addClass("selected");       
    testid = $("tr.selected td").attr("value"); 
    });

    $(document).on('hover', function(e) {
    $(document).on('keydown', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    if (e.which == 38) { 
    if ($('.selected').prev('td').hasClass("header")) {
  alert("Don't move to header row");

     } else {
  $('.selected').prev('tr').addClass('selected').siblings().removeClass('selected');
  testid = $("tr.selected td").attr("value"); 
  $.ajax({
    url: '../aksesuar/testkod.php',  
    type: 'POST',   
    data: { 'kateqoriya': testid } , 
    success: function(data){
        $('#testaksesuar').html(data);   
           $('#aksesuaryeni').attr('value', testid);       
    }
 });
}
                       
           } else if (e.which == 40) { 
           if ($('.selected').next('tr').length == 0) {
           } else {

  $('.selected').next('tr').addClass('selected').siblings().removeClass('selected');
  testid = $("tr.selected td").attr("value"); 
  $.ajax({
    url: '../aksesuar/testkod.php',  
    type: 'POST',   
    data: { 'kateqoriya': testid } , 
    success: function(data){
        $('#testaksesuar').html(data);   
           $('#aksesuaryeni').attr('value', testid);      
    }
    });
    }

    } 
    });
    }); 
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

The demonstration below works as you request, you can select a row in a table (it is then highlighted in yellow, and that table gains a blue border). The up and down keys can then be used once a table/row is selected.

If you click on a different table then you do not lose the selection in your previous table, but the up and down keys will only work on the newly selected table. If you want to unselect all rows on changing tables then there is a line in the code below that you can uncomment.

The code checks to see if you are at the end of the table (either the top or the bottom), and also stops you from selecting the header row (with class `.header`).

**Updated** to add click events to tables in case data is being added dynamically.

**Updated** to run `selectionChanged()` function after each valid selection change (i.e. not when the arrow is pressed at the top or bottom of the table or when you click again on an already selected row);

The code is fully commented.

Let me know if you were hoping for something else.

---

```js
// Add click event listener to document, check for clicks on rows
// Better to use: $("table").on... as long as the table exists when this script is run then this will pick up dynamic rows added later
// Do not allow clicks on tr with class header
$(document).on("click", "tr:not(.header)", function() {

  // As you can only change selected table with a click
  // It is more efficient to only change selected table here
  
  // Remove last selected table
  $("table.selected").removeClass("selected");
  
  // Add selection to the current table
  $(this).closest("table").addClass("selected");
  
  
  // Check if clicked row is already selected
  // If it is then we can exit
  // Remove this if you want to run the selectionChange function when clicking back into a table
  if ( $(this).hasClass("selected") ) {
    return;
  }
 
  // Pass new selection to function
  selectionChange($(this));

});

// Monitor for keyup events
$(document).keyup(function(e) {

  if (e.keyCode == '38') { // Up arrow pressed

    // Find selected row in current table
    row = $("table.selected").find("tr.selected");

    // Check if row above exists
    // Check if it is a header
    if (row.prev().length != 0 && row.prev().hasClass("header") == false) {

      // Pass new selection to function
      selectionChange(row.prev());

    }

  } else if (e.keyCode == '40') { // Down arrow pressed

    // Find selected row in current table
    row = $("table.selected").find("tr.selected");

    // Check if row above exists
    if (row.next().length != 0) {
    
      // Pass new selection to function
      selectionChange(row.next());
    
    }

  }


});


// Function to run after change in row selection
function selectionChange(newRow) {

  // Remove selected rows in current table
  $("table.selected").find("tr.selected").removeClass("selected");
  
  // Add selected class to row
  newRow.addClass("selected");
  
  // Add AJAX call here
  // This will run after every valid change of selection
  //  $.ajax({
  //  url: '../aksesuar/testkod.php',  
  //  type: 'POST',   
  //  data: { 'kateqoriya': testid } , 
  //  success: function(data){
  //      $('#testaksesuar').html(data);   
  //         $('#aksesuaryeni').attr('value', testid);       //   }


}


// Create extra rows here to demonstrate dynamic rows are working
// Do not include this in your project - dmeo purposes only
// Loop through each table
$("table").each( function() {

  // Loop 3 times
  for (i = 0; i < 3; i++) { 
  
  // Clone the last row and append it to the table
    $(this).append($(this).find("tr").last().clone())
  }

});
```

```css
tr.selected {
  background: yellow;
}

table.selected {
  border: blue 1px solid;
}

.selected-function {
color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="table-1">

  <tr class="header">
    <th>Header One</th>
    <th>Header Two</th>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td>Cell One</td>
    <td>Cell Two</td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td>Cell One</td>
    <td>Cell Two</td>
  </tr>

</table>

<hr>

<table id="table-2">

  <tr class="header">
    <th>Header One</th>
    <th>Header Two</th>
  </tr>
  
  <tr>
    <td>Cell One</td>
    <td>Cell Two</td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td>Cell One</td>
    <td>Cell Two</td>
  </tr>

</table>
```

Comment: I've updated the example to include the check for the header, and also to ensure that the functionality will work with dynamically created rows. I've re-jigged it so that it runs a common function whenever a row is changed - I have added where I think you should have your AJAX command run

Comment: Updated - use `$(document).on("click", "tr:not(.header)", function() {`- it isn't good practice to add a click event to the document as it isn't very efficient. But this will work for any tables that you create later

Comment: You'll need to remove one of the code elements I'm afraid